# Intercepting Eclipse e4 platform exceptions

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Using Eclipse RCP 3.x, it is possible to create a custom AbstractStatusHandler to intercept platform exceptions. One way to do this, is to override the getWorkbenchErrorHandler() method in the ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class like this:

```
    @Override
    public synchronized AbstractStatusHandler getWorkbenchErrorHandler()
    {
        if (m_errorHandler == null)
        {
            m_errorHandler = new MyWorkbenchErrorHandler(this);
        }
        return m_errorHandler;
    }
```

After doing a lot of research in Eclipse forums, stackoverflow and in the Lars Vogel Eclipse 4 book, I have not been able to find an equivalent way to do this using e4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything that uses this seems to be in 'org.eclipse.ui.xxx' plugins so it does not seem to apply to e4 at all.

Comment: @greg-449 That's exactly the problem. Global  error handling is such a basic feature that it's hard for me to understand why can't I find information about how to do it on e4

Comment: This really isn't global error handling, it only seems to be used by various UI operations and dialogs in the org.eclipse.ui plugins - there are no equivalents of these operations and dialogs exist in e4.

Answer (score 0):

You can put our own `IEventLoopAdvisor` into the context. A good place to do this is on `@PostContructCreate` in your life cycle handler.

```
context.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, new IEventLoopAdvisor() {
        @Override
        public void eventLoopException(Throwable exception) {
            ... handle exception here ...
        }

        ...
    });
```

If there is no `IEventLoopAdvisor` in the context the platform will use a default. You can see how the platform does this in `PartRenderingEngine` (at the time of writing on line 1102):

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/internal/workbench/swt/PartRenderingEngine.java

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We found that we can achieve what we want by using the Platform.addLogListener(...). This way we get informed about exceptions handled by the platform.

Comment: `IEventLoopAdvisor` is in an `internal` package so is not part of the official API