# Java - Catch all stacktraces

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application for which I would like to capture all stacktraces. I am currently using slf4j for my logging mechansim.  As an example, if I run my RCP application within eclipse, I can look at the console window and see any stacktraces that have not been explicitly captured by the code.  If I export the application and run it outside of eclipse I will not see those stacktraces.  I do not wish to tediously change the code to use try/catch blocks (because there is a LOT of code).  I would rather tap into whatever mechanism Eclipse uses to do the same thing (It does not put try/catch inside my code, yet it reports it in the console).  Is there an easy way to do what Eclipse does inside my RCP code so that when I run it from outside eclipse it shows up in my log files?

Comment: When you run your RCP from within Eclipse a new JVM is started to run it. The Eclipse console just shows everything that the new JVM outputs. So this isn't something you can use outside of Eclipse. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29900137/2670892) mentions some methods you could try.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but that link shows an RCP 3x way and an internal package way.  Neither would be avaliable solution. Did I miss another way?

Comment: Although IEventLoopAdvisor is an internal class it seems to be the best way to catch unhandled exception in e4. Quite a few e4 APIs are still classed as internal because the design is still not absolutely finialized. They are unlikely to change significantly (certainly OK in Eclipse Oxygen released this month).

Comment: I tried the code shown in the link for the IEventLoopAdvisor but it doesn't contain the same messages that the eclipse console does. (I placed the code inside the @PostContextCreate just like in the example code). FWIW I'm using Mars2 (4.5.2)

Comment: FYI I also tried the Platform.addLogListener() but that didnt capture what is in the eclipse console either

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the RCP framework; but normally, you can setup a **thread group** handler for uncaught exceptions.

In other words: you can define a component that is triggered for each and any uncaught exception. And that component could simply log incoming exceptions.

See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/threadgroup_uncaughtexception.htm) for some example code.